# MySQL Date format Question

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, datetime

How do i convert  06 Aug 2010 03:41:44 GMT+00:00 to mm/dd/yy time in mysql?

I basically want to sort this SentDate column (the data is populated from an external source).
I am ok to do this in c# also.

Comment: Store those dates as a `DATETIME` type and life will be easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert it in your select statement, use the [following](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%y')
FROM   TableName
```

If you want to do it in code.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
string strDateTime = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT('06 Aug 2010 03:41:44 GMT+00:00', '%m/%d/%y') return error - incorrect datetime

Comment: And this value is coming from a column in a table?

Comment: You could also try STR_TO_DATE('06 Aug 2010 03:41:44 GMT+00:00', '%m/%d/%y').  I don't have access to mysql right now to test, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get a specific format for your datetime fields, you can do something like this:

```
select 
    concat(
        month(date_field),
        "/",
        day(date_field),
        "/",
        year(date_field)
    ) 
as 
    formatted_date 
from 
    myTable;
order by
    date_field asc;
```

However, I'm not sure that this works with other field types - might well do though, so can try.

Answer (score 0):

Hang on. Do you want to convert it to mm/dd/yy format, or do you want to sort it by date/time? The two are not conducive to one another.

### Sorting

If the column is already a `datetime` column in MySQL, then you can sort it normally:

```
var query = db.MyTable.Where(...)
    .OrderBy(row => row.SentDate);
```

If the column is a *string* column (`varchar`), then you will need to convert the data to a `DateTime` object as you read it from the database, and *then* sort it in C#. For example:

```
var query = db.MyTable.Where(...)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new { row, Sent = DateTime.Parse(row.SentDate) })
    .OrderBy(inf => inf.Sent);
```

The call to `AsEnumerable` causes the data to be retrieved, so the DateTime parsing and the sorting happens in C# land instead of on the DB.

### Converting to mm/dd/yy

One way to convert a `DateTime` to a `string` in the format you described is to use `.ToString` explicitly:

```
datetime.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
```

Another is to use the US-American culture:

```
datetime.ToString("d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

However, the latter appears to use single-digit months.

Once you’ve converted a `DateTime` to such a string, sorting it makes no sense because you would be sorting it by the first digit of the month — nobody would find that useful.